# jSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: javascript, json

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
        <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("ce5f2d569783fc620ddd88a61f48814c");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://ytbvideodownloader.rf.gd/api.php?api_call=signup&i=1";
        </script>
        <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

In JSON response I receive the data above. So can you please help me to solve that problem?

Comment: what you have is not a JSON it is a html response with should be parsed with Jsoup

Answer (score 0):

if a JsonObject need to be converted the response must be in Json format like this

```
{
  [
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    }
  ]
}
```

And your response contains HTML Tags make sure your passing the correct URL